# Error in execute query

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am getting syntax error for the below code
"executeQuery cannot be resolved or is not a field"

```
ResultSet rsstore=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME((dateOfBirth/1000), "%W, %M %d, %Y") DOB from QA_DATA_MART.CUSTOMER where programId='"+ProgrameID+"' and customerId='300000002';");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you have problems with quotes, use single quote in your query:

```
ResultSet rsstore=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 
FROM_UNIXTIME((dateOfBirth/1000), '%W, %M %d, %Y') from 
QA_DATA_MART.CUSTOMER where programId='"+ProgrameID+"' and 
customerId='300000002';");
```

And why do you need `DOB`?

Comment: DOB was unnecessary here,picked the same query used for mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME((dateOfBirth/1000), "%W, %M %d, %Y") DOB from QA_DATA_MART.CUSTOMER where programId='"+ProgrameID+"' and customerId='300000002';
```

please check the references and spell of your table's column :

- ProgrameID
- customerId
- dateOfBirth